# Run AWS MediaConvert job over entire S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-media-convert

I have an S3 bucket with tens of thousands of audio files and thousands of video files that I need to transpose via MediaConvert.

Before I go ahead and write a function that I can run as a lambda to iterate the bucket and start all of MediaConvert jobs, is there a less laborious approach to achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 1):

AWS Elemental MediaConvert does not natively have that functionality; however, there is a GitHub project that leverages CloudFormation templates to create a stack for simulating "Watchfolder" processing between S3 and MediaConvert via Lambda functions.

Here's a link to the project:  https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-media-services-vod-automation/tree/master/MediaConvert-WorkflowWatchFolderAndNotification

From the project's README.md file:

> Walkthrough of the Workflow
>
> 1. The Ingest user uploads a video to the WatchFolder bucket /inputs
>    folder in S3. Only files added to the /inputs folder will trigger
>    the workflow.
> 2. The s3:PutItem event triggers a Lambda function that calls
>    MediaConvert to convert the videos.
> 3. Converted videos are stored in S3 by MediaConvert.
> 4. When the conversion job finishes MediaConvert emits aws:mediaconvert
>    Job State Change Event type CloudWatch events with the job status.
> 5. The COMPLETE and ERROR status events trigger SNS to send
>    notifications to subscribers.

Since the Lambda is triggered by s3:PutItem events, this means you may have to move those tens of thousands of assets to the /inputs folder which could incur costs.